# How to disable multiple images using script in Unity?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

[Screenshot of Unity hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCYb.png), [Images stay on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPRlv.png) I'm currently having problem to disable images in Unity. I have about 26 buttons in same scene making it tedious to use OnClick() one by one. I'm trying to disable 25 images when one button is clicked. For example, I click button A which display image A. When I click button B, the previous image did not disappear but stay below image B. I have tried `i.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;` and `i.gameObject.SetActive(false);` but failed.

```
public GameObject[] exceptions;
public void DisableImg()
{
    GameObject[] image = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("image");
    foreach (GameObject i in image)
    {
        i.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     //   i.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
    }    

    foreach (GameObject g in exceptions)
    {
        g.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     //   g.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to know the hierarchy of your images and button object to help you ..and how you display image

Comment: if you hold clicked object, then compare it in first foreach and check if(clickedImage != Gameobject) then write that in if scope i.gameObject.SetActive(false);

Answer (score 0):

This code will work, you did not tag your images properly, its something you have to manually set in the inspector.

```
public GameObject[] exceptions;
public void DisableImg()
{
    GameObject[] image = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("image");
    foreach (GameObject i in image)
    {
        i.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     //   i.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
    }    

    foreach (GameObject g in exceptions)
    {
        g.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     //   g.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

It is inefficient though to fill the image array each time, unless you are dynamically adding and removing GameObjects tagged with 'image' during the game.

```
void Start() {
        GameObject[] image = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("image");
}
```

You can also fill the array without this start function or having it in DisableImg() method by going to the inspector, on image in the component type the number of images, then you can drag and drop the gameobjects into the array.

[image]

Make sure your images are tagged like this in the inspector, you can click the current tag in the dropdown and scroll down and create a new tag. You then can go back and set all images to have that tag.

Comment: I did tag my image. Maybe there is something I miss. Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it

Comment: Update: As nothing works, I just put all images into 3 separate panels according to keyboard row and use OnClick() whenever I need the images as a temporary measure.